# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: debugging

I am getting this Error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/sites/default/settings.php:1) in
> drupal_send_headers() (line 1236 of
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> Warning:
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
> started at
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/sites/default/settings.php:1) in
> drupal_send_headers() (line 1236 of
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> Warning:
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
> started at
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/sites/default/settings.php:1) in
> drupal_send_headers() (line 1236 of
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>
> Warning:
> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output
> started at
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/sites/default/settings.php:1) in
> drupal_send_headers() (line 1236 of
> /home/aigair1/public_html/site1/includes/bootstrap.inc).

I don't get this when my website in Localhost(Xampp), But When I upload site to web I get this. What's problem ?

[Here](http://aiga.ir/setting.txt) is the Setting.php file as txt

Comment: did you check this post: http://is.gd/CbgSgu

Comment: Clear all cache and check this **Warning**  gone OR not? Let know what is result.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, Yes I did it but problem exist

Answer (score 2):

There is an output in your settings.php file. Maybe a whitespace before `<?php`, maybe you closed PHP tag at the end of your file, can't know without seeing it. Inspect your file carefully.

Be sure to transfer your files in binary mode, and disable all automated conversions your FTP software may offer. Save files as utf8 without BOM, Linux line endings. That's the safest way. If your editor can't do that, use another.

As Daniel Tome correctly pointed out, it may be case of warning turned off on your localhost, not a transfer issue. But the things you need to check are the same either way.

Comment: I attached setting file in question

Comment: @Ali **Don't** - this is not a private support forum, this is Q&A site - knowledge base for all of us, and for future users. If you feel you need yo attach whole files, you are in wrong place.

Comment: Sorry for URL, I fixed it.

Comment: Also it's possible that your localhost has warnings turned off and your web has warnings turned on. Molot's answer is the correct. Your settings.php is outputting probably at the beginning of the file.

Comment: See the file, it has been attached to question

Comment: @Ali no I won't. See my first comment here.

Comment: I commented the line in bootstrap.inc and warning gone. By now I didn't see any error. Is it good way ?

Comment: @Ali No, it's worst way. You broke functionality you don't understand to avoid fixing error you made elsewhere. So wrong, on so many levels...

Comment: All option that you mentioned doesn't fix problem, So What should I do ?

Comment: @Ali earn enough reputation to go to chat with it, or hire a consultant. This it's not a **personal support** service. Community we serve for free. Individuals? Most of us do it for money. Exaggerating a bit, by asking us to do our jobs for free you are taking our food from us...