# remote Drush stops because of " headers already sent"

Tags: drush

I am struggling with a remote drush error since days, and don't find the cause. I already checked the Internet up and down for an answer, but could not find a solution for my problem ([here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167839/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by),[here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75952/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent) and many more):

I have one specific D7 setup that I remotely manage by drush, running Drush 8 on both sides (started with 7 on both sides, and upgraded meanwhile both to 8)
My local Drush can do a `drush @anysite_in_aliases status` and it works, so I assume there is no problem at my local drush.
My remote drush can do that as well - if I log in at my remote server and call `drush status` in the drupal directory, it works.

Only if I call `drush @specialsite status` I get this:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                          [error]
```

I tried to use `--debug` on it, the relevant part is:

```
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.28 sec, 8.04 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.28 sec, 8.04 MB]                                      [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=7) [0.28 sec, 8.04 MB]                                                  [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.28 sec, 8.04 MB]                                     [bootstrap]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                             [warning]
phar:///home/example/bin/drush/includes/output.inc:41) common.inc:705 [1.16 sec, 32.14 MB]
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [1.17 sec, 32.68 MB]                     [error]
End redispatch via drush_invoke_process(). [3.62 sec, 7.99 MB]                                             [notice]
```

And here I stuck. I know that there must be a whitespace before/after a php tag somewhere, or an error message that is sent before the header. But I can't find out where I can get nearer to the culprit.
I've read up and down [all the causes for that error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) - but my problem is: WHAT causes that error??

BTW: I am using Uberspace as server (CentOS 6), already thought maybe is drush called as php-cgi?? How do I check this?

My aliases lines:

```
$aliases['example.live'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://example.org',
  'root' => '/var/www/virtual/example/html',
  'remote-host' => 'example.org',
  'remote-user' => 'example',
);
```

Could anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Interesting problem. Are you able to run "drush rq" locally and remotely and compare the output? I see the output that causes "headers already sent" is coming from includes/output.inc Are you capable of editing that file so we can get the output?

Comment: aaaaahhhhh. That could be the culprit. I get a `The following module is missing from the file system: <em class="placeholder"> ...` This is given out at stderr I suppose, and therefore causing that problem. At the remote version this problem does not occur. And yes, I can edit what I want, have full access. But maybe we don't need that any more.

Comment: Nup. Adding the 2 modules that seemed to be missing locally did not do the trick. `drush rq` now runs without an error, but I still cant do a `drush @remote status`. `drush rq` output following ASAP.

Comment: Here is the local output: http://pastebin.com/3rHnzinf - and here is the remote one: http://pastebin.com/mrGf3L5F

Comment: I meant the output from ```drush rq``` for the same server but run locally (on the remote server) and remotely using a site alias. This is the output from two different machines.

Comment: ah yes, sorry. here is it from the server A directly again: http://pastebin.com/PtTf3UtU - and here from my problem server B, reaching out for server A with a site alias: http://pastebin.com/bHprv7zd (this is with --debug)
You can't really compare it as the "remote" one does not really give any output except `Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]` - without the `--debug` flag

Comment: It was a long shot - that "drush rq" worked remotely. As I said earlier you need to start to edit files and dive into the code to debug/find out what is going on. In addition to checking what is output by includes/output.inc you could do a backtrace on line 705 of includes/common.inc (in Drupal, not Drush) - when the function drupal_goto calls the PHP header function. Good luck!